# Building a json message in groovy using Json builder

Tags: json

I am facing a problem in building the json message, i need a json message to be in the below format:

```
{
  success:true,
  count:3,
  data: [
         {id:1, data: SUCCESS},
         {id:2, data: FAILURE},
         {id:3, data: Not Declared}
        ]
}
```

Im anot sure how to do this plz help

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the following way:

```
class Data { String id; String data }
def yourdata = [
    new Data("1","SUCCESS")
    new Data("2","FAILURE")
    new ... 
]    

def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()

def root = builder {
    success true
    count 3
    data yourdata.collect { d ->
        ["id":d.id, 
        "data":d.data]
    }

}

return builder.toPrettyString()
```